# How to between timestamp and timestamp in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two queries

Query #1 works:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbPLC.dbo.PLC_CPacking3KW2P3 AS A 
INNER JOIN dbPLC.dbo.PLC_CPacking3KW2P3 AS B ON B.NoUrut = A.NoUrut - 1 
WHERE A.Nilai - B.Nilai = 1 
  AND CONVERT(DATE, A.TimeStamp) = CONVERT(DATE, '2017/08/13') 
  AND DATEPART(HOUR, DATEADD(DAY, 1, A.TimeStamp)) BETWEEN 7 AND 15
```

But I want to query between 07:00:00 and 15:00:00

Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this

```
convert(varchar(8),convert(time,A.TimeStamp)) between '07:00:00' and '15:00:00'
```

instead of this

```
DATEPART(HOUR,DATEADD(DAY,1,A.TimeStamp)) between 7 and 15
```